# Mysql update with join on db2 conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I have this query that is structured more for mysql

```
 update metrics m join
   (select repnumber, material, item, color, sum(m2.velocity)/count(*) as avg_velocity
    from metrics m2
    group by repnumber, material, item, color
   ) m2
   using (repnumber, material, item, color)
set m.repvolocity = m2.avg_velocity;
```

Is there a way to change this to work for db2?

Answer (score 3):

In DB2 (and most other databases) you would use a correlated subquery:

```
update metrics m
    set repvolocity = (select avg(m2.velocity)
                       from materials m2
                       where m2.repnumber = m.repnumber and m2.material = m.material and m2.item = m.item and m2.color = m.color
                      );
```

I should note that DB2 also makes it easy to calculate the value on the fly:

```
select m.*,
       avg(m.velocity) over (partition by repnumber, material, item, color) as repvelocity
from materials;
```

With window functions, you may find that there is no need to actually store the value.  I should add that MySQL 8+ also has this capability.